# Determining the expressions of the coefficients of the full Fourier series from the Complex Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $l \gt 0$ be a positive real number, and $\phi:[-l,l]\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ be the function defined by: $$\forall x\epsilon[-l,l], \phi(x)=e^x $$

(1) Calculate the coefficients of the Full Fourier Series of $\phi$ over the interval $[-l,l]$ under their complex form

(2) Deduce from this result the expression of the coefficients of the Full Fourier series of $\phi$ over $[-l,l]$ under their real form.

Here is what I have so far:

(1) Note $\phi(x)={1\over{2l}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_ne^{{in\pi x}\over{l}}$
$$c_n={1\over{2l}}\int_{-l}^le^xe^{{-in\pi x}\over l}dx = {1\over{2l}}\left[{1\over{1-{in\pi\over{l}}}}e^{x\left(1-{in\pi\over{l}}\right)}\right]_{-l}^l={1\over{2l}}\left[{l\over{l-in\pi}}\left(e^{l-in\pi}-e^{-l+in\pi}\right)\right] $$

Evaluating when n is odd and n is even:$c_n={(-1)^n\over{2l}}\left[{l\over{l-in\pi}}sinh(l)\right]$

$$\phi(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over{2l}}\left[{l\over{l-in\pi}}sinh(l)\right]e^{{in\pi x}\over{l}} $$

Now, I'm not sure how to use this to determine the coefficients of the full Fourier series.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What you have so far  is the Fourier series in complex form. To turn it into real form, plug
$$e^{{in\pi x}\over{l}} = \cos {n\pi x \over l} + i \sin {n\pi x \over l}$$
into the series. After multiplying   this by 
$$\left[{l\over{l-in\pi}}\sinh(l)\right]$$
separate the real and imaginary parts. The imaginary part is going to add up to $0$ since the function is real (indeed, the term labeled $-n$ kills the term labeled $n$), so you may as well drop it  now. The real part is the series you want.